# Routes.rb edit form redirect fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm doing 2 forms, 1 for create and 1 for edit. The create form works great. The edit form generates this error

```
No route matches [PATCH] "/admin/posts/14/edit"
```

In the form, I guess the problem is "patch". I changed that for "edit" and url admin_posts_path, like the "create" form, but this produces a new item, not edit the current one. This is my rake routes on this part

```
             admin_posts GET    /admin/posts(.:format)           admin/posts#index
                         POST   /admin/posts(.:format)           admin/posts#create
          new_admin_post GET    /admin/posts/new(.:format)       admin/posts#new
         edit_admin_post GET    /admin/posts/:id/edit(.:format)  admin/posts#edit
              admin_post GET    /admin/posts/:id(.:format)       admin/posts#show
                         PUT    /admin/posts/:id(.:format)       admin/posts#update
                         DELETE /admin/posts/:id(.:format)
```

And this is the form or at least the important part

```
<%= form_for :post, url: edit_admin_post_path(@post),:html => { :multipart => true }, method: :patch do |f| %>
```

Comment: so why are you creating separate form for `create` and `edit`?

Comment: because i cant figure out the url for a form, jajaja im sure i cant figure out that. jaja, but i will, i promess

Comment: check my solution below, may be it can solve you problem with single form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `edit` action only responds to GET requests. The actual update is done in the `update` action, which responds to PUT (or PATCH if you use Rails 4).

Your edit form should start with this:

```
<%= form_for :post, url: admin_post_path(@post),:html => { :multipart => true }, method: :put do |f| %>
```

You could also simplify this to:

```
<%= form_for @post, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
```

This will automatically set the form action to `PUT admin/posts/:id` for existing records, and `POST admin/posts` for new records.

Comment: Thanks im using rails 3.2

Comment: actually i think the lesson i was using for edit is for rails 4, in the controller also there is a line with permit that now is the issue "undefined method `permit'" (thats for rails 4) right?

Comment: If you're not stuck to Rails 3.2, you could decide to upgrade to 4. Otherwise you need to use `attr_accessible` in your models, like explained here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attr_accessible/class

Comment: i always do, use attr_accessible, but in the controller, in the lesson i was using as reference, they use this line in controller  @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :text, :postimage))  // this does not work for rails 3.2

Comment: done, i just change that for this : @post.update_attributes(params[:post])

Comment: Correct. It's the Rails 4 replacement for 3.2's `attr_accessible`. It was decided that attribute whitelisting should be done in the controller rather than the model.

Answer (score 1):

`edit_admin_post` only for GET http verb.

Your form should reference to `PUT /admin/posts/:id` to update your post.

change your form to:

```
<%= form_for @post, { multipart: true } do |f| %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: so how do i fix it, or how(where) do i change get for post?

Comment: change your form to <%= form_for @post do |f| %>

<% end %>

Answer (score 1):

If your `create` action is working then you don't need to pass `url` for edit. Rails can determine which path to choose by calling `new_record?` method. If object is `new_record` than rails will use `admin/posts#create` method but if you object is not `new_record` than rails will use `admin/posts#update` method. So your controller will look like this

```
class Admin::PostsController < ApplicationController
   def new
     @post = Post.new
   end

   def create
     //some code
   end

   def edit
     @post = Post.find(params[:id])
   end

   def update
     //some code
   end
 end
```

and than you can create `form` like this

```
 form_for @post do |f|
   //code here
 end
```

now rails can automatically determine which path to use for `new` post and `editing` post

Comment: Wow, i really would try this, one question.. in the form , they are actually the same form? wow thats cool , but how do i create a "Edit" link in each if i dont have the edit.. and the new is not pointing to an id

Comment: ya with this approach you don't need two forms

Comment: sorry maybe you dont see my edit in comment. "thats cool , but how do i create a "Edit" link for each post if i dont have the edit.. and the new is not pointing to an id "

Comment: you don't need `id` for create but you will need `id` for edit thats why in controller i have method `def edit; @post = Post.find(params[:id]); end` it will depend how you have defined your routes but normally you can use `link_to "Edit", edit_admin_post(@post)`. Did you notice i pass `@post` inside edit_admin_post method. Rails will automatically get `id` for given `post`. If you have more questions then please let me know. And yes with this approach you will need only `one` form. Hope this helps.